# Unable to delete user via Azure AD B2c Graph API

Tags: azure

I'm trying to delete Azure AD B2C user via Graph API but it says:

```
{ 
   "odata.error":{ 
      "code":"Authorization_RequestDenied",
      "message":{ 
         "lang":"en",
         "value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
      },
      "requestId":"2978aff2-0ccc-43a8-8405-905c7f6ed259",
      "date":"2019-09-16T06:12:50"
   }
}
```

I've already set Required permissions via Azure Active Directory, and also provided Directory Role of Company Administrator via Azure Powershell.

```
public async Task<string> SendDeleteRequest(string api)
{
        await AuthenticateClientAsync();
        var url = "https://graph.windows.net/<tenant-name>/users/<user-object-id>?api-version=1.6";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, url);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authenticationToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.SendAsync(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            object formatted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(error);
            throw new WebException("Error Calling the Graph API: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatted, Formatting.Indented));
        }

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

The response response.IsSuccessStatusCode is always false.

Am I missing anything for successful delete?

Comment: Can you show how you get the access token?

Comment: I used the access token generated via successful login from Browser Console. I copied it and used it in Postman Header.

Comment: You need to acquire a token in your code using e.g. ADAL and with client credentials (client id + secret). There should not be a user login.

Comment: The token is issued by B2C. This generated access token is validating all other requests except for deleting user.